# Recursive feature elimination with mlr

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, mlr

It is possible to conduct a recursive feature elimination feature (rfe) with mlr ?
I know this is possible with caret [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html) but even if there is some documentation about feature selection with mlr, I did not find an equivalent to rfe.

Comment: Just in Addition to @missuse's answer, here some more info from the mlr tutorial: https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr/articles/tutorial/feature_selection.html#wrapper-methods . As you can see, there are also much more (smarter) strategies for feature selection (including genetic algorithms).

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks for the link. But why genetic algorithm would be a better strategy than rfe to select features ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To perform recursive feature elimination in mlr you can use the function  `makeFeatSelControlSequential` with the argument `method = sbs` (sequential backwards selection). Here is an example of usage using `lda` learner :

```
library(mlr)
ctrl <- makeFeatSelControlSequential(method = "sbs",
                                     beta = 0.005)

rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3)

sfeats <- selectFeatures(learner = "classif.lda",
                         task = sonar.task,
                         resampling = rdesc,
                         control = ctrl,
                         show.info = FALSE)


FeatSel result:
Features (57): V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V11, V12, V13, V14, V15, V16, V17, V18, V19, V21, V22, V23, V24, V25, V26, V27, V28, V29, V30, V31, V32, V33, V34, V35, V36, V37, V38, V39, V40, V41, V42, V43, V44, V45, V46, V47, V48, V49, V50, V51, V52, V53, V54, V55, V56, V57, V58, V60
mmce.test.mean=0.2066943
```

here, 57 variables out of 60 were selected.

you can use:

```
analyzeFeatSelResult(sfeats)
```

to get a hold of the selection path

```
#output
    Path to optimum:
- Features:   60  Init   :                       Perf = 0.26936  Diff: NA  *
- Features:   59  Remove : V59                   Perf = 0.2403  Diff: 0.029055  *
- Features:   58  Remove : V10                   Perf = 0.22588  Diff: 0.014424  *
- Features:   57  Remove : V20                   Perf = 0.20669  Diff: 0.019186  *

Stopped, because no improving feature was found.
```

Comment: Thanks but shouldn't I use the beta parameter instead of alpha for backward selection ?

Comment: @MassCorr you are correct, I have edited the answer to reflect that.